# Can't install node.js with coffeescript on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript

Tried to install node.js with coffeescript like [this](http://www.gaggl.com/2012/07/coffeescript-on-ubuntu-12-04/):

```
sudo sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

But:

```
coffee -v
```

Returns me:

```
Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (module.js:388:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lapsa/bin/coffee@1.3.0:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:903:3
```

I'm completely lost at the moment. Any help?

---

Tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516034/nodejs-and-coffeescript-install-ubuntu-12-04) w/o success.

```
$ npm -v
1.2.15

$ node -v
v0.11.0-pre

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163447/error-require-paths-is-removed-use-node-modules-folders-or-the-node-path-envi

Comment: @HectorCorrea it didn't. might be I didn't delete all old stuff, unsure about that.

Comment: In node odd version numbers are under development and have new api. Try the stable 0.10.x node version.

Comment: @user568109 did try it. no success

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me (tested on both Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

Source:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Note that it does not use the default Ubuntu package `npm`. Instead `npm` is packaged with in Chris Lea's `nodejs` package.

If you already have `npm` installed, you might want to remove it first before applying the workaround above. Note that there is also a naming conflict with a package named `node` but which has nothing to do with nodejs. If you installed that package by accident, you might also want to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if your problem is related to trying to install npm using

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

If you take a look at the instructions for [installing nodejs via package manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) it states that

```
As of Node.js v0.10.0, the nodejs package from Chris Lea's repo includes both npm and nodejs-dev.
```

I wonder if a rogue installed version of an npm package is causing you a problem. I ran into this the other day but for me, npm just wouldn't install.